# How would I separate left and right audio from a soundcard into two inputs, and later combine them together

Tags: audio, microphone, system-sounds, sound-editing, audio-processing

I have a Steinberg UR22 mk2 soundcard, which I use for my mic and for my guitar, and I can set it up so that my mic is the left channel and my guitar is the right channel.

Is it possible to separate the two channels into recording devices, so that I can use software to modify my voice and use digital guitar pedals without them affecting each other, and to later combine them back into one audio input (and possibly to mono audio but not required) that could be used as an input in a Windows application.

Comment: Any DAW can do that. Record into two mono channels rather than one stereo.

Comment: I cant find any DAWs that would allow me to get an output. My intention is not to record audio, but to have fun on voice channels with friends.

Comment: That's a different task entirely. Something like [Voicemeeter Banana](https://www.vb-audio.com/Voicemeeter/banana.htm) might be able to do something like that. I had assumed as you had a Steinberg interface you were dealing in ASIO routing.